# Make user made entries in /etc/hosts permanent

Tags: vpn, openvpn, hosts

I use Juniper Networks network connect to connect to the office network. Once i am inside the office network, i check the server ips and add entries for them in /etc/hosts file like,

```
10.199.xx.yy  offi
```

When i come out of the VPN network into public domain, network connect resets all changes it made and brings my `/etc/hosts` file to the state it was in before entering the network. I think, this behaviour is Juniper Network connect's expected behaviour as it adds an entry on the top of the `hosts` file as,

```
# BEGIN hosts added by Network Connect
61.xx.yy.zz  vpn.ip.com
# END hosts added by Network Connect
```

But in trying to reset its own entries, network connect reset the user made entries as well..

I tried to make `/etc/hosts` as immutable using `chattr +i /etc/hosts` but that caused my vpn login to fail as network connect comes out, if it fails to write into `/etc/hosts`

Comment: See [How to prevent Juniper Network Connect breaking DNS resolutions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156154/how-to-prevent-juniper-network-connect-breaking-dns-resolutions) and possibly http://www.petitbourgeois.com/2012/04/cisco-network-connect-vpn-client-messes-around-with-my-hosts-file/#comment-865

Comment: No idea about Juniper Network; try asking on serverfault? Judging by the entries to the beginning of the `/etc/hosts` file, it looks like a service called "Network Connect" automatically adds those lines to the file.  So, find out how to configure the service so that it changes that behavior to your liking, or file a bug with their developer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I can't tell whether IP/hostname mappings are permanent in your office.  If they are, you might want to make a little script that resets the `/etc/hosts`file:

```
cat > /etc/hosts <<EOF
10.199.0.23   foo
10.199.0.24   bar
10.199.0.31   baz
10.199.0.39   quux
EOF
```

and that you run when you want to reset the IP/hosts mappings.